# implementing android navigation drawer in my existing extended Activity

Tags: navigation-drawer, toolbar, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity, appcompat-v7-toolbar

I have an activity that already extended with An Activity But now I want App Compat Activity in my App. Actually I want my menu from left side. How can I Do this ?

```
    public class MainContentActivity extends DraggableNowPlayingSheetActivity {
     //code here
    }
```

[image]